# jQuery Text Completer

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I would like to add text completer in fields of my form. I don't really know how they call it, I just thought the closest would be "text completer".

What I want it to do is very simple. Let say I want to write "Broken DC Jack". I want my code to start guessing what I am going to write and give me up to 3 selections when I write "Broken". Example; "Broken CPU", "Broken Memory", "Broken DC Jack" so I can choose which ever I want then I don`t have to continue writing whole phrase, it adds itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're aren't up for implementing your own. jQueryUI has a pretty decent autocomplete with examples.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
        ];
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
    </script>



<div class="demo">

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags">
</div>

</div><!-- End demo -->



<div class="demo-description" style="display: none; ">
<p>The Autocomplete widgets provides suggestions while you type into the field. Here the suggestions are tags for programming languages, give "ja" (for Java or JavaScript) a try.</p>
<p>The datasource is a simple JavaScript array, provided to the widget using the source-option.</p>
</div><!-- End demo-description -->
```

Comment: $(ele).autocomplete()? Really!?  I just spent an hour rewriting an autocomplete function(s) on a project to match the new data requirements... Reminds me of the time last year I wrote a jQuery date-picker from scratch 1 month before a sexy one was released. Such is life :)

Comment: jqueryui makes it quite simple, even with XHR requests.  On the other hand, writing your own implementations is great experience and can often lead to an api that fits your application better.

Answer (score 1):

It's called `auto-complete`

JQuery UI has this widget, check [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) out

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/